# Optimization to avoid jitters on cardboard app when moving camera with head on Android

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, profiling, google-cardboard

I am working on a cardboard application for android platform. Currently I have Light-maps, heavy textures and around 100 UI elements in scene (most of them have text components with stock Arial font from Unity3D standard assets and few ScrollRect and Mask components). Running application on cardboard in a bit jittery overall when I move head to look around in the scene and shows spikes on Profiler when I load a new menu. Profiler view from a frame is shown in the image below :

[image]
Has anyone faced this issue before?

Can someone point me to right direction of optimization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking question about Unity C# optimization seems to get downvotes for no reason. That's not right. It is important to some who know what they are doing. Anyways, are you using `OnGUI` anywhere in your script? Search for every script. Are you instantiating each frame?

Comment: @Programmer I have some scripts in my projects which contains OnGUI but not included in scene, except 1 virtual OnGUI method without implementation which I am not overriding anywhere.

Comment: Try to find them then remove them temporary. It is very likely you have them. `GUITargetAttribute` is showing in the Profiler and that usually appear when `OnGUI` is used. That alone allocates 356 bytes.

Comment: It is in code from 3rd party demo scenes, So I don't think that will have an effect. Instead, can you see `ScrollRect.LateUpdate()` is allocated 6.7K? I get these spikes whenever some elements are disabled and others are enabled.

Comment: I found problem to this and I am making an answer for optimizing UI in Unity.

Comment: Thanks! I spent few hours to optimize my code and its a bit better now. But still have spikes in coroutines and sometimes ScrollRect.LateUpda‌​te() gets 10MB gc allocation.