# ScrollRect.LateUpdate() spike in profiler allocating GC upto 2.4MB

Tags: performance, optimization, unity-game-engine, garbage-collection, profiling

Following up [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959670/optimization-to-avoid-jitters-on-cardboard-app-when-moving-camera-with-head-on-a) regarding Profiler spikes. I have just figured out that if I enable deep profile option in Unity3D I can see `GetComponent()` call under `ScrollRect.LateUpdate()` is taking up to 2.4 MB memory for garbage collection for only 5 `Scroll Rect` components. As it is obvious from the following snapshot that Unity is calling `Component.GetComponent()` for 4046 times in `LateUpdate()` method which causes performance issue. My application is UI intense, but 2.4MB for GC is not accepable at all.

[image]

Usually It is recommended not to use `GetComponent()` in any of update methods but Unity's own implementation is breaking the convention. Which limits the number of UI items I can have in one scene to avoid the performance issues.

Note this profiling data is only from the frame when I activate a menu object.

Is there any workaround to reduce/save 2.4MB of memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Usually It is recommended not to use GetComponent() in any of update
>   methods but Unity's own implementation is breaking the convention

Unity's `GetComponent()` does **not** allocate memory when the Application it is built. Build the Application to verify this. It allocates memory **only** in the Editor.

Unity made a [post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) about this few years ago:

> We do this in the editor only. This is why when you call
>   GetComponent() to query for a component that doesn’t exist, that you
>   see a C# memory allocation happening, because we are generating this
>   custom warning string inside the newly allocated fake null object.
>   This memory allocation does not happen in built games. This is a very
>   good example why if you are profiling your game, you should always
>   profile the actual standalone player or mobile player, and not profile
>   the editor, since we do a lot of extra security / safety / usage
>   checks in the editor to make your life easier, at the expense of some
>   performance. When profiling for performance and memory allocations,
>   never profile the editor, always profile the built game.

It is recommended to profile the real game instead of the one from the Editor.