# Improve Frame rate on too many UI Images - Unity UI

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

In my single page, there were so many textures those I require to render before I was just facing problem in just screen opening but this I was able to resolve this suggestion:

[OnBecomeVisible for Canvas UI Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314314/onbecomevisible-for-canvas-ui-objects)

Here is the actual code that I used for this purpose:

```
public void OnValueChangeRefreshCards (Vector2 valueChange)
{
    elapsedYDist += valueChange.y;

    if (elapsedYDist > 3f) {
        elapsedYDist = 0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < GameConstants.TOTAL_ROSE_COUNT; i++) {
            Card card = roseList [i].GetComponent<Card> ();

            if (RendererExtensions.IsVisibleFrom (card.MyRectTransform, Camera.main))
                card.roseImage.enabled = true;
            else
                card.roseImage.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But now I started too much framerate lose related issue so even scrolling of page become really difficult for me.
Please check the attached video for more clearance about the issue, I was facing.
[NameThatRose - Low Frame Rate](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10axNqK_H_sCyTiqE86UOk1kNC2FrVRRH)

Please give me some suggestions for next improvements.

**EDIT:** Here are my profiler output.

- Detailed Deep Profiler
  [image]
- Overview Deep Profiler
  [image]

Comment: If not done already, pack your sprites in Sprite Packing. You can do this by giving a Packing tag in the texture import editor. Unity will pack those with same tag until full texture, then it packs them in a secondary one. You can do that yourself creating atlas map and importing your texture as multiple sprite. Then with SpriteEditor you can cut them. This will minimize the draw calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can try few things to find out whats causing the low fps.

1. Use [profiler](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/introduction-profiler) to deep profile to find out which UI call is taking more time. Like what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959670/optimization-to-avoid-jitters-on-cardboard-app-when-moving-camera-with-head-on-a).
   As Image inherits from `UIMaskableGraphics`, it calls `MaskableGraphics.OnEnable()` every frame for every image in your list. This takes up time which you can see here:

[image]

2. I believe your `OnValueChanged` method is called every frame this would only multiply the enable/disable iterations and its processing time. You can limit the call by some time, processing 4 times a second for example.

   ```
   float timeSinceLastUpdate = 0;

   void Update()
   {
       timeSinceLastUpdate += Time.deltaTime;
   }

   public void OnValueChangeRefreshCards (Vector2 valueChange)
   {
       if(timeSinceLastUpdate < 0.25f)
       {
           return;
       }
       timeSinceLastUpdate = 0;

       // do your stuff here...
   }
   ```
3. You have 250+ images to process every frame which is a big deal for older Android devices, again as `MaskableGraphics.OnEnable()` call can be the culprit. You can avoid changing the state if it is required:

   ```
   if (RendererExtensions.IsVisibleFrom (card.MyRectTransform, Camera.main))
   {
       if(!card.roseImage.enalbed)
           card.roseImage.enabled = true;
   }
   else
   {
       if(card.roseImage.enalbed)
           card.roseImage.enabled = false;     
   }
   ```

---

Furthermore, following are some helpful links to optimize UI in Unity:

- [Some of the best optimization tips for Unity UI](https://create.unity3d.com/Unity-UI-optimization-tips)
- [Tantzy Games](http://www.tantzygames.com/blog/optimizing-unity-ui/)
- [Gemserk](http://blog.gemserk.com/2017/07/20/our-tips-to-improve-unity-ui-performance-when-making-games-for-mobile-devices/)
- [Other UI Optimization Techniques and Tips](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/other-ui-optimization-techniques-and-tips)
- [A guide to optimizing Unity UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/temas/best-practices/guide-optimizing-unity-ui)

### UPDATE:

The following blog provides more information about UI rendering:

- [Making the UI Backend Faster](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/09/07/making-the-ui-backend-faster/)

---

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your side quick reply. Basically I require to remain continue with RendererExtensions.IsVisibleFrom or I require to change this with MaskableGraphics ?

Comment: Second point, I was already not change status of images on each frame, I have calculated drag distance that you can check in my above code.

Comment: First of all use profiler to find out your problem. Image _IS_ MaskableGraphics and you are already using it when you are using images. Keep using your extension code and change code from point 3.

Comment: Okay I am doing both mentioned steps and get back to you.

Comment: Please check I have added profiler images for giving clear loading issues.

Comment: No but let me see by enabling that whether any difference in output or not!!

Comment: I have updated my images with Deep Profile flag enabled.

Comment: I can see there are too many draw calls. Read the articles that I have linked to learn how to optimize and minimize draw calls for UI.

Comment: Yes thank you sir :) Let me carefully go through above blog content.

Comment: In blog they have not mentioned any way of improvement, all I get in latest version of Unity and already I was using Unity 2017.1.2p2

Comment: All other links I posted have valuable information on optimization. Read them all :)